# SQL: selecting unique values based on conditions

Tags: sql, performance, conditional-statements

I have a table containing 5 columns. The first column contains an ID, two columns contain parameters for those IDs with the values 0 or 1, a third column contains a parameter which I need as output, the last column contains a date. The same ID can appear in several rows with different parameters:

```
ID        parameter1      parameter2        parameter3       date

001       0               1                 A                01.01.2010
001       0               1                 B                02.01.2010
001       1               0                 C                01.01.2010
001       1               1                 D                01.01.2010
002       0               1                 A                01.01.2010
```

For each unique ID I want to return the value in `parameter3`, the decision from which row to return this value is based on the values in `parameter1` and `parameter2` and the date:

- If there is a row with both parameters being `0`, I want the value in this row.
- If there is no such row, I want the value from the row where parameter1 is `0` and parameter2 is `1`,
- If there is no such row, I want the row where parameter1 is `1` and parameter2 is `0`.
- Finally, if there is no such row, I want the value from the row with both parameters being `1`.

If there is more than one row matching the required conditions, I want the row with the most recent date.

e.g., for the table above, for the ID `001` I would want the second row with the value `B` in parameter3.

What would be the most effective / fastest way to accomplish this? I tried two approaches so far:

the first one was to select all distinct IDs and then loop through the distinct IDs, using a `select` statement with the ID in the `where` clause and then loop through all the rows matching the ID while storing the necessary values in variables.:

```
foreach
    select distinct ID into i_ID from table1
        foreach
            let o_case = 5
            select case
                when parameter1 = 0 and parameter2 = 0 then 1
                when parameter1 = 0 and parameter2 = 1 then 2
                when parameter1 = 1 and parameter2 = 0 then 3
                when parameter1 = 1 and parameter2 = 1 then 4
                end, parameter3, date
                into i_case, i_p3, i_date
                from table3
                where table3.ID = i_ID

                if i_case < o_case 
                    then let o_p3, o_case, o_date = i_p3, i_case, i_date;
                    else ( if i_case = o_case and i_date > o_date
                        then let o_p3, o_date = i_p3, i_date;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end foreach;
        insert into table_output values(i_ID; o_p3);
end foreach;
```

The second approach was to left join the table four times with itself on the ID and apply the different combinations of the parameter1 & parameter2 as described above in the left joins, then selecting the output via nested `nvl` clauses:

```
select ID, 
    nvl(t1.parameter3, 
        nvl(t2.parameter3,
            nvl(t3.parameter3,
                nvl(t4.parameter3)))) parameter3
from table1 t0
    left join table1 t1
        on t0.ID = t1.ID and t1.parameter1 = 0 and t1.parameter2 = 0
        and t1.date = (select max(date) from table1 t1a where t1a.ID = t1.ID)        
    left join table1 t2
        on t0.ID = t2.ID and t2.parameter1 = 0 and t2.parameter2 = 1
        and t2.date = (select max(date) from table1 t2a where t2a.ID = t1.ID)
    left join table1 t3
        on t0.ID = t3.ID and t3.parameter1 = 1 and t3.parameter2 = 0
        and t3.date = (select max(date) from table1 t3a where t3a.ID = t3.ID)
    left join table1 t4
        on t0.ID = t4.ID and t4.parameter1 = 1 and t4.parameter2 = 1
        and t4.date = (select max(date) from table1 t4a where t4a.ID = t4.ID)
```

Both approaches basically worked, however, as the table is really long, they were much too slow. What would you recommend?

PS: DBMS is IBM Informix 10, this unfortunately restricts the range of available functions a lot.

Comment: Please could you edit your post to include code blocks which show the two SQL queries you tried. Also, it might be worth stating what DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but this could work:

```
SELECT id, parameter3
FROM (
    SELECT id, parameter3, RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id, parameter3
            ORDER BY parameter1 ASC, parameter2 ASC, date DESC
        )
    FROM tab
) AS x
WHERE x.rank = 1;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am stuck to IBM Informix 10. rank over doesn't work there, as well as subqueries in the from clause

Answer (score 0):

```
ID        parameter1      parameter2        parameter3       date

001       0               1                 A                01.01.2010
001       0               1                 B                02.01.2010
```

both of the above rows having same ID, paramaeter1, parameter2 but different paraameter3, it can create trouble for you.

Comment: I included this on purpose to demonstrate the chararacteristic of the table. There may be cases where the same ID with the same values in parameter 0 and 1 exists in multiple rows. However, in this case the date will be different